# Using BeautifulSoup to ignore certain elements in a list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use the following list comprehension to retrieve the title attribute of a BeautifulSoup object.

```
[i.find(class_ = 'turnstileLink')['title'] for i in soup_obj.find_all(class_ = 'jobtitle')]
```

However it's failing because the first element doesn't have a title object.

```
[i for i in soup_obj.find_all(class_ = 'jobtitle')][0]

<a class="jobtitle" data-tn-element="jobTitle" href="/ita?id=21544&amp;tk=1clc5blpc5ihif01&amp;flowPage=jasxserp&amp;flowType=inline&amp;q=babysitter&amp;l=Austin%2C+TX&amp;adLoc=Austin%2C+TX&amp;fromita=1" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Nanny, Babysitter, Daycare Worker, Childcare Worker</a>
```

But the remaining elements do contain that attribute.

```
[i for i in soup_obj.find_all(class_ = 'jobtitle')][1]

<h2 class="jobtitle" id="jl_916e5029c0a9d994">
<a class="turnstileLink" data-tn-element="jobTitle" href="/company/LA-Fitness/jobs/Babysitter-Kids-Klub-916e5029c0a9d994?fccid=0b9d9ba80ad80eea&amp;vjs=3" onclick="setRefineByCookie(['radius']); return rclk(this,jobmap[0],true,0);" onmousedown="return rclk(this,jobmap[0],0);" rel="noopener nofollow" target="_blank" title="Babysitter/Kids Klub"><b>Babysitter</b>/Kids Klub</a>
</h2>
```

Therefore when I grab an element individually that's not element 0, this seems to work

FYI: here is the script that created soup_obj

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=babysitter&l=Austin,+TX&sort=date&limit=10&radius=25'
page = requests.get(url)
soup_obj = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
```

Apologies if any of this is difficult to digest, I'm still a relative newbie to BeautifulSoup and python in general. Can provide more detail if needed

Comment: You could just instantiate an empty list and then append to that list inside of a try-except block, which would handle the error if the title object does not exist.

Comment: Is there a way to exclude elements inside the list comphrension?  I'm fine with doing what you suggest, but wondering whether there's a more "compact" way to do ti.

Comment: using `.get('title')` will prevent `KeyErrors` from being thrown and will return a default of `None`. That will allow your list comprehension to execute and you can ignore `None`s by adding `if i.find(class_="turnstilelink").get('title')` at the end

Answer (score 0):

To avoid `KeyErrors` in `dict`-like objects, it can be helpful to use `get`:

```
[i.find(class_ = 'turnstileLink').get('title') for i in soup_obj.find_all(class_ = 'jobtitle') if i.find(class_ = 'turnstileLink').get('title')]
```

Although that can make it a bit harder to read. You may prefer to use:

```
gen = [i.find(class_ = 'turnstileLink').get('title') for i in soup_obj.find_all(class_ = 'jobtitle')]

links = [g for g in gen if g]
```

For readability's sake